# Problems with Firebase integration android

Tags: android, firebase

I have a problems with Firebase integration on my android application. I have done everything that was described in official tutorial. I added this code in **project build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    repositories {
        google()
       ...
    }
    dependencies {
       ...
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
...
```

Also I appended this to the bottom of **app build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Of course I did not forget to add **google-service.json** into app directory

But i stuck in "Application connection verification with google service" here
[image: Application connection verification with google service]

The connection to the Firebase is not established. I don't understand what I did wrong. Help me please. 
1) Application has access to internet. (It is already working with it)
2) I have opened the application after integration 
3) I  tried to reinstall application
[image]

Comment: did you open your app after integration ?

Comment: @Swayangjit Yes, of course

Comment: Just uninstall and install the app again would help

Comment: @RohitSuthar I have already done that, it did not help

Comment: Start app again and Check log messages

Comment: @RohitSuthar nothing strange there. Screenshot will be in my question soon.

Comment: Are you using  emulator or real device ?

Comment: @Swayangjit I am using real device

Comment: What is your Google Play services version ? is it the latest, check in Android SDK tools(Tools -> Android -> SDK manager -> SDK tools tab)

Comment: @Swayangjit 15.0.1

Comment: is there any option to update it ?

Comment: @Swayangjit I will try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202121/discussion-between-swayangjit-and-kostya-m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found my mistake. It was pretty stupid - someone previously had left another ** google-service.json ** file in a project in a different directory. I have not seen it. 
Maybe someone will find it useful how I determinated this error 
If you are not sure that google-service.json has been parsed correctly you should look at  **app>build>generated>res>google-services>[buildType]>values>values.xml**.If everything is OK, then this file will contain the same data as in your google-service.json file. 
[image]